# Сравнение дата-атрибутов и текущей даты

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, не подскажете как получить все значения дата атрибутов и сравнить их с текущей датой.
Пытаюсь сделать слайдер, в котором вместо дотов будет дата, но надо,чтобы при загрузке страницы всегда была текущая дата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока есть вот такой код

```
<div class="slider-nav">
  <div data-date="2019-07-18" class="slider-nav__item">
    <h3><span>18 июля</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div data-date="2019-07-28" class="slider-nav__item">
    <h3><span>28 июля</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div data-date="2019-07-29" class="slider-nav__item">
    <h3><span>29 июля</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div data-date="2019-07-30" class="slider-nav__item">
    <h3><span>30 июля</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div data-date="2019-07-31" class="slider-nav__item">
    <h3><span>31 июля</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div data-date="2019-08-01" class="slider-nav__item">
    <h3><span>1 августа</span></h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Не совсем понимаю, как привести дату к требуемому виду и отобразить

```
var date = new Date;
var res = date.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");

console.log(date);
console.log(res)

var item = $('.slider-nav__item').attr('data-date');

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получение значений data-атрибутов:

```
var item = $('.slider-nav__item').data('date');
```

Получение текущей даты в требуемом виде:

```
var res = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Весь код с сравнением:

```
var date = new Date;
var res = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
$('.slider-nav__item').each(function(){
   if ($(this).data('date') === res) {
       // дата слайда равна текущей, делаем что-то
   }
});
```

**UPD:**

Если нужно просто обратиться к слайдам с текущей, то можно без цикла, например:

```
$(".slider-nav__item[data-date='" + res + "']").addClass('current');
```